# Understanding Ruby Inheritance

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I've been reading the Well Grounded Rubyist and it mentions how a class inherits the instance methods of its super class so that objects of the class will be able to call those instance methods.  Here's an example:

```
class C
  def run_instance_method
    puts "This is an instance method."
  end
  def C.run_class_method
    puts "This is a class method."
  end
end

class D < C
end
```

Based on what I've read, it's always been described that class D would inherit just the instance methods of class C (in which case, the C::run_class_method would not be inherited by D).  However, after running the above code, I notice that:

```
D.run_class_method # => "This is a class method."
```

Here's my guess as to why this is happening and please let me know if this is the correct understanding. If there is an instance d of class D and you try to run d.run_instance_method, that object will search its method-lookup path and see if that method is defined in its singleton class, its own class, or in its superclasses.  Since run_instance_method is defined in class C, no issues will occur and run_instance_method will be called.  For the class object D (which is a subclass of C and Object), if D.run_class_method is called, it'll again check the method lookup path for the D class object.  Again, Ruby will find it in the class object C.

Is this reasoning accurate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Class methods may be inherited and overridden just as instance methods can be. If your parent class defines a class method, the subclass inherits that method. That is, if your subclass does not define it's own class method, then it inherits from it's superclass.

As a recommendation: when invoking a class method with an explicit receiver, you should avoid relying on inheritance. Always invoke the class method through the class that defines it. Otherwise, it would be very difficult for someone who relies on your code to find the parent class which defines the class method.

Referring back to your original assumption: the invocation of a class method from a subclass it's possible because the class methods are instance methods of the `eigenclass`.

```
class C
   # instance methods goes here
   class << self # open the eigenclass
   # class methods go here as instance methods of the eigenclass
   end
end
```

In general, it's clearer to define class methods as individual singleton methods without explicitly opening the eigenclass.

For a clear explanation read [The Ruby Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177) by David Flanagan and Yukihiro Matsumoto

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Can you correct me if I'm incorrect with this explanation: basically, all class methods reside in their eigenclass as instance methods. If class D inherits from its superclass class C, then class D's eigenclass implicitly inherits from class C's eigenclass as well. And it's for this reason that the class object D can call .run_class_method. Is this accurate?

Comment: Exactly! When Ruby evaluates a method invocation expression first has to figure out which method needs to be invoked. This is what is called `method lookup`: first search for method definition in the self class, if no method is found, then search in the class parent etc. up to the chain root.

Answer (score 2):

Not very exactly. There is another concept hidden here, called `metaclass` or `eigenclass`. The class method is inherited from eigenclass. See [Ruby Hacking Guide](http://rhg.rubyforge.org/chapter04.html) for more information about it. ( Just search for "class methods" in the page if you don't want to read them all. )